# Duplicate Div - Remove option prevents additional Div Duplication

Tags: javascript

I'm new to using javascript and have come up against a bit of a wall where I was looking for code to duplicate a DIV. I found the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="myform">
<input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="duplicate()">

<div id="original"> 
    duplicate EVERYTHING INSIDE THIS DIV
</div>

<div id="duplicater"> 
    duplicate EVERYTHING INSIDE THIS DIV
<input type="button" value="Remove Div" onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none'">
</div>

<script>
var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');

function duplicate() {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.id = "duplicater" + ++i;
    // or clone.id = ""; if the divs don't need an ID
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works quite well. I added a Remove Div button so if the user decided they added one Div too many they would have the option to remove it. However, in testing I found if the user Remove Div all the way back to the first Div, any further Duplicate Div does not display. So the user would have to restart the page. To resolve this I tried to include an IF...ELSE.

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="myform">
<input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="duplicate()">

<div id="original"> 
    duplicate EVERYTHING INSIDE THIS DIV
</div>

<div id="duplicater"> 
    duplicate EVERYTHING INSIDE THIS DIV
<input type="button" value="Remove Div" onclick="this.parentNode.style.display        = 'none'">
</div>

<script>
var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');

function duplicate() {
if (document.getElementById("duplicater")=="none")
{
document.getElementById("duplicater")="";
}
else
{
var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
clone.id = "duplicater" + ++i;
// or clone.id = ""; if the divs don't need an ID
original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, this does not work. I fully admit to being no coding guru and wouldn't be surprised if it is a simply syntax issue, but any points with this would be greatfully accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
this.parentNode.style.display = 'none'
```

This is setting the parent node (the `form`) to not display (which isn't the same as removing it). What you want to do is find the `lastChild` to the of the parent node and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Matt has your answer, I got distracted so here's a late response. In your code:

```
> <input type="button" value="Remove Div" onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none'">
```

does not "remove" the node, it just hides it. To remove the node:

```
<input type="button" value="Remove Div" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)">
```

Also:

```
> if (document.getElementById("duplicater")=="none")
```

*getElementById* returns either a DOM node with a matching ID, or *null* if there isn't one. Neither will ever be equivalent to the string "none", therefore the above will always return false. Which is a good thing because in the line:

```
> document.getElementById("duplicater")=""
```

You will be trying to assign to *null* or a DOM element, both of which are not permitted. In the case that the left hand side evaluates to *null* , an error will result. Where it resolves to a DOM element, anything can happen (since host objects can do what they like) but likely an error will result.